# Is there any way to watch for a registry value change with Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I want to create a powershell script that would allow me to do "something" when the value in a certain registry key changes. This would be to know when the background of windows change with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper`

I've tried using a watcher, but I can't make it work, it is the first time I work with regstry keys.

Here is my current code :

```
$registryKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop"
$registryValue = "Wallpaper"

$nodePath = "C:\path\to\node.exe"
$indexPath = "C:\path\to\index.js"

$initialValue = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryKey -Name $registryValue

$watcher = New-Object Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey -ArgumentList $registryKey
$onChange = { 
    # Get the new value of the registry key
    $newValue = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryKey -Name $registryValue
    
    # Execute the Node.js program with the new value as an argument
    $nodeArgs = "--path=$newValue"
    & $nodePath $indexPath $nodeArgs
}

$watcherChangeEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher `
    -EventName "ValueChanged" -Action $onChange
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/powershell-registry-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do while loop to check for the value to change

```
do {
    Write-Host "-->Waiting for update in the registry 
checkpoint...";
}
while ((Get-ItemProperty -Path 
"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session 
Manager\Environment" -Name "Task-USERDATA" -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue)."Task-USERDATA" -ne 1);
if((Get-ItemProperty -Path 
"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session 
Manager\Environment" -Name "Task-USERDATA" -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue)."Task-USERDATA" -eq 1)){
    Write-Host "<-- Update in the registry checkpoint detected.";
 
}
```